# remove flaws in text after conversion using PDF OCR technique

Tags: text-formatting

I convert PDF file using OCR PDF reader. originally the text was an images in the PDF file and PDF Foxit convert it to text using OCR now the problem after conversion is the text is not aligned correctly it seems all words and lines where shifted. sample text

```
  biochemistry can be divided in three fields; molecular genetics, protein science and metabolism. Over the last decades 
of the 20th century, biochem
istry has through these three disciplines becom
e successful at explaining living processes. Almost all areas o
f the life sciences are being uncovered and developed by biochemical methodology and research.[2] Biochemistry focuses on unde
rstanding how biolog
ical molecules give 
rise to the processes that occur within living cells and
 between cells,[3] which
 in turn relates greatly to the study and understanding of 
, organs, and organism structure and function[4]

Biochemistry is closely related to mol
ecular biology, the study of the molecular mechanisms by which geneti
c information encoded in DNA is able to result in the processes of life.[5]

Much of biochemistry deals with the structu
res, 
 an
d interactions of biological macromolecules, such as proteins, nucleic acids, carbohydrates and lipids, which provide the structure of cells and perform many of the functions associated with life.[6] The chemistry of the cell also depends on the 
 of smaller molecules and ions. Th
ese can be inorganic, for example water and metal ions, or organic, for example the amino acids, which are used to synthesi
ze proteins.[7]
 The mechanisms by which cells harness energy from their environment via chemical reactions are known as metabolism. The findings of biochemistry are applied primarily in medicine, nutrition, and agriculture. In medicine, b
iochemists investigate the causes and cures of diseases.[8] In nutrition, they study how to maintain health wellness and study the effects of nutritional deficiencies.[9] In agriculture, biochemists investigate soil and fertilizers, and try to discover ways to improve crop cultivation, crop storage and pest control.
```

the problem also some words are cutted in half. is there any thing I can do to fix the text so it is readable.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `awk` linear to remove extra carriage returns, something like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n/,""); gsub(/\r/,""); print}' RS='' file

biochemistry can be divided in three fields; molecular genetics, protein science and metabolism. Over the last decades of the 20th century, biochemistry has through these three disciplines become successful at explaining living processes. Almost all areas of the life sciences are being uncovered and developed by biochemical methodology and research.[2] Biochemistry focuses on understanding how biological molecules give rise to the processes that occur within living cells and between cells,[3] which in turn relates greatly to the study and understanding of , organs, and organism structure and function[4]
Biochemistry is closely related to molecular biology, the study of the molecular mechanisms by which genetic information encoded in DNA is able to result in the processes of life.[5]
Much of biochemistry deals with the structures,  and interactions of biological macromolecules, such as proteins, nucleic acids, carbohydrates and lipids, which provide the structure of cells and perform many of the functions associated with life.[6] The chemistry of the cell also depends on the  of smaller molecules and ions. These can be inorganic, for example water and metal ions, or organic, for example the amino acids, which are used to synthesize proteins.[7] The mechanisms by which cells harness energy from their environment via chemical reactions are known as metabolism. The findings of biochemistry are applied primarily in medicine, nutrition, and agriculture. In medicine, biochemists investigate the causes and cures of diseases.[8] In nutrition, they study how to maintain health wellness and study the effects of nutritional deficiencies.[9] In agriculture, biochemists investigate soil and fertilizers, and try to discover ways to improve crop cultivation, crop storage and pest control.
```

`gsub` function has the following form:

```
gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])
```

This is similar to the sub function, except gsub replaces all of the longest, leftmost, non-overlapping matching substrings it can find. The `g' in gsub stands for "global," which means replace everywhere

```
gsub(/\n/,"") replaces all newline occurrences within a string with non for all input text. 

gsub(/\r/,"") replace all carriage return (ASCII code 13) occurrences with non for all input text.
```

Comment: this is amazing thank you so much. i know some basics in awk but couldn't make it work. can you please explain the command ?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably room for improvement, but here's a start:

```
perl -0777 -ne 's/([^ ])$\\n/\1/g; s/\\n/ /g; print' < input | fmt
```

It uses perl to combine newlines -- continuing lines if the line ends with a blank, otherwise stripping newlines altogether, then pipe the output through `fmt` to break long lines back up.